# Mysql instance of AWS got hacked

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Today I opened my application and I can see its not working at all. I checked my logs and I saw tables were not found. I opened my mysql administrator and I can see my data wiped and a table created with name PLEASE_READ_ME_XMG

[image: created table]

[image: Created a row to send him some money]

What are possibilities of getting hacked?

My mistake is I added public access for my instance. But how can he find my db host address, username, password.

I wanna know he hacked into my db using my web application or using my db instance directly. Can I find that?

These are the logs I should check or have any other logs to check?
[image: logs]

I saw a log in my db logs: **[Warning] [MY-010056] [Server] Host name 'hostby.fcloud.biz' could not be resolved: Name or service not known**
Is this something I should look into?

Comment: TBH, it doesn't really matter how they did. AWS RDS MySQL uses Basic Auth by default, so there are few if any circumstances in which a MySQL service should be public. If it was public, it was a matter of when this happened, not if. There are millions of bots with un:pw dbs roaming the internet looking for exploits like this. You're wasting your time figuring how the why and how. Restore (if you can) and protect with the network in future.

Comment: Ya restored for now so how can I protect my network now @GarrethMcDaid

Comment: The only sources that should be able to connect are your application server(s) and whatever system you do your DBadmin from. This is generally actioned in AWS with Security Groups and/or VPN NACLs. Whatever you do, make sure its not accessible from the public internet.

Comment: Ok I will change my security groups to be accesible only for my server and my local development laptop. Is this enough to secure or should add any other securities? @GarrethMcDaid. But what if he did this using my web application?

Comment: Does your application MySQL user have the necessary permissions to delete entire DB tables?

Comment: Where can I check that I have no idea abt that @GarrethMcDaid. Can u guide me

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL and web server logs.

Assuming the attacker didn't get filesystem access and delete them, you should be able to figure out his initial entry point based off the timestamps in the logs and his IP address.

Comment: I updated my post pls check are those the logs I should check?

Comment: Those are MySQL error logs, the best log for this type of auditing would be the general log file containing access information. By default it is named `mysql.log`.

Comment: Where can I find it??? I updated my post with a HostName can u please check it

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS and its web interface but I'm sure it's in there somewhere, a quick google search can probably answer that question. Regarding the hostname, it doesn't mean anything without more context. You pulled this from the error log file but the information you want is in the general/access log file.

Comment: ok thanks will check them. Thanks for your time